# Struct/Field Variables with Python

Tags: python, matlab

I would like to know if it is possible to create struct variables and their respective fields in Python as it is possible in MATLAB.

For example: I want to create a struct variable with the name of a person and their characteristics as fields:

```
John.name = 'John'
John.age = 30
John.sex = 'Male'
John.height = 1.85
John.weight = 85
```

Then I will perform some operations with these variables, for example checking if John is over 18:

```
if John.age > 18: ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Structs are not present in python, as everything is looked at as an object.

My best suggestion is to make a [class](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) for what you originally intended the structure to do. Something similar to:

```py
class Person:
  def __init__(self, name, age, height, weight):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
    self.height = height
    self.weight = weight

# creating the object
john = Person('John', 20, 184, 75)

# Accessing the fields

if john.age > 18:
  ...
```

Alternatively, you could use a dictionary

```py
John = {}

# setting a field
John['age'] = 20

# using a field
if John['age'] > 18:
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

There are different constructs that you can use and which one is the most suitable depends on what exactly you intend to do with it. With the example you've given and assuming the values of the attributes are not changing, [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) could be a good candidate here:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Person = namedtuple("Person", ["name", "age", "sex", "height", "weight"])

John = Person("John", 30, "Male", 1.85, 85)

if John.age > 18:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use dictionaries for example

```
John = {
'name'   :  'John'
'age'    :  30
'sex'    :  'Male'
'height' :  1.85
'weight' :  85
}

if John['age'] > 18:
    print('older than 18')
```

or other way you  can use OOP "Objective oriented programming" for example:

```
    #creation class with name person:
    class person:

        #define init function to initialize main variables:
        def __init__(self, name, age,sex,height,weight):

            #define main variables you want to store and use
            self.name    = name
            self.age     = age
            self.sex     = sex
            self.height  = height
            self.weight  = weight
    
    #using class to store data you  want:
    John = person('John',30,'Male',1.85,85)
    Mario = person('Mario',25,'Male',1.90,80)

    #using data you stored:
    print(John.name)
    print(John.age)
    print(Mario.sex)
    
    #and your example is ready
    if John.age > 18: ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use classes to implement struct.

```py
class Person:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for i in kwargs:
            setattr(self, i, kwargs[i])

john = Person(name="John", age=30)
print(john.name, john.age)  # John 30
```